# Export from calibre to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, ebook, calibre

I am using calibre for my e-book management software. Is there any way to export  whole database (Tags, tiles, authors list), so that I can import to wordpress blog?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I just gone to tools -> import (on wordpress) and found nothing.
Neither csv